# dismissing a view never calls completion function

Tags: ios, swift, closures, interface-builder

When I dismiss a view it refuses to trigger the completion function and I don't know why.

[image]

Here I expect the print statement to execute but it never does.

```
@IBAction func tapBack(_ sender: Any) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        print("this should print")
    })
}
```

Source Code

https://github.com/omenking/DismissCompletion

I also tried wrapping it in `DispatchQueue.main.async` but I had no luck.

Comment: That is because you are popping the view controller and then dismissing whatever it is presenting. After the view controller is popped, it is deinitialized and lost forever in the fabric of spacetime (ideally). Dismiss first, pop last. You can pop in the dismiss completion handler if that suits your UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you not be better off calling the function on the tap? Example:

```
func dismissController() {
  self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And then on your button:

```
@IBAction func tapBack(_ sender: Any) {
  dismissController()
  print("this should print")
}
```

I've just downloaded your project and tried this and it prints.

Comment: My plan is to use the notification center to message another view. I had consider this never tested it because I thought it made sense to capture it is the completion closure. I will see if this works, but I would like to know why completion closure never gets called if I can find out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , I am assuming that since you are `popping the view controller`, you must have `pushed it into the navigation Stack`.

Secondly, if you did do it , then `self.dismiss` method will never get called because you are already popping the view controller before it.

If you want the `completion` block to work, you should `present the ViewController` instead of `pushing` it.Then, you can write your code in the `completion` block and it will execute.